# Floats working, but are now stepping.

Tags: css, css-float

This page:

The boxes were originally floating fine and showing 4 products across the middle. After a coleague copied and pasted the exact same code from notepad, other than a URL change, the floating issue has occurred. I have looked through and can't see the culprit.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing closing `div` tags:

```
...
<div class=xmashp-bottom-box-price>From Only £9.99</div><!--<div style="float: left; width: 35px;"> </div>-->
<div class=hp-bottom-box1>
...
```

so your `hp-bottom-box*` boxes are nested inside each other.  Add a closing `</div>` tag before you open the next `hp-bottom-box*` tag and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you richsage, that has worked - for some reason when copy/pasting notepad has removed some closing div tags and almost all "" from div classes.

I have gone through and fixed most the errors, if you check the page now you will see they are inline but are still hovering over the content rather than pushing the content down. have you any ideas?

Comment: @Wayners247 only just saw this - but looks like you got it fixed judging by your site :-)

Comment: Yea, but I fixed it by putting in a div height rather than it being dynamic, was only a quick fix and not my preferred method. Im trying to figure out why its done it. thanks for your help :)